# Cabal hell to install cabal-nirvana?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I'm trying to install cabal-nirvana on OSX 10.7.5, but I get the following output:

```
cabal install cabal-nirvana
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading cabal-nirvana-0.2.2...
Configuring cabal-nirvana-0.2.2...
Building cabal-nirvana-0.2.2...
Preprocessing executable 'cabal-nirvana' for cabal-nirvana-0.2.2...
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id HTTP-4000.2.3-c26f702c170ca487dfea54c2f3d6d4c0
    (use -v for more information)
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cabal-nirvana-0.2.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Any ideas?

In case it helps,
ghc: 7.4.1
cabal-install: 0.14.0

When I do ghc-pkg check, I get the following output:

```
WARNING: cache is out of date: /Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.4.1-    i386/usr/lib/ghc-7.4.1/package.conf.d/package.cache
  use 'ghc-pkg recache' to fix.
Warning: haddock-interfaces: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.1/lib/GLUT-2.1.2.1/doc/html/GLUT.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
Warning: haddock-interfaces: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.1/lib/haskell-platform-2012.2.0.0/doc/html/haskell-platform.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
Warning: haddock-html: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.1/lib/haskell-platform-2012.2.0.0/doc/html doesn't exist or isn't a directory
```

Comment: What happens when you use `ghc-pkg check`?

Comment: I'll put the output in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind... I did the 'ghc-pkg recache' and a 'sudo cabal update cabal-install', and then I was able to install cabal-nirvana without issues... The keyword here appears to be 'sudo'... D'oh!

... And by "Nevermind" I don't mean the Nirvana album :)

Comment: Uh ouch, you really seldom should use `sudo cabal install`. Are you sure it's justified in this case?

Comment: I didn't know that... What is a better alternative?

Comment: Never using `sudo` with cabal.

Comment: The interesting question though is why it helped or was necessary in this case. In fact on OS X it is, at least with my setup, frequently necessary to use `sudo cabal install` (`-- user` implicit) as otherwise the use of `gcc` is inhibited. But this isn't that sort of case.

Comment: On Arch Linux it stores everything under ~/. Is that not the case on OSX machines as well?

Comment: Yes they are, but the location of files has absolutely nothing to do with what privileges might be necessary to change or generate them, especially when the latter is a complex process. People often think that `sudo cabal install pony` installs `can-i-have-a-pony` in `/usr/../bin` but `cabal` of course has no idea it was called with superuser privileges, and the executable will go into `~/.cabal/bin`      As far as I can see all the remarks above are based on the opposite idea.